# secure WebApi2 c#, Remote on-premise ADFS 3.00 and Javascript client

Tags: javascript, c#, client, asp.net-web-api2, adfs3.0

we have a c# webapi2 api that our javascript web app communicates with. They are both hosted from the same server under the same domain.

The web Api2 project was not set up with any authentication as it was discussed that the whole api and client might need to connect and authenticate with a remote on premise ADFS server.

It has been given that the JavaScript client and webApi must now authenticate with the remote  'on-premise'  ADFS server (this ADFS server is a separate organisation and not on 'our-premise') .
They are using ADFS 3.00 set up on Windows server 2012 r2

So far we have the following information

ADFS server url.
from this, we can access

-ADFS fedration metadata xml 
-their ADFS sign in page which we must use, and somehow redirect back to somewhere(javascript client or web api?)

I'm sure we can access more items from this ADFS server url - like authcode, token..etc from their server but not sure what is relevant or not.

I first of all want to know what should happen after a user authenticates via their ADFS sign in page. should the sign in page have a return url that hits our c# api with a token?

If so, how do we consume this token in the api call and read user information from it. The only claim we are looking for is the email address.

The api is a webapi2 in c#.

Any help or solutions would be greatly appreciated based on the current setup.

Answer (score 0):

ADFS 3.0 is somewhat limited in its OAuth support - essentially Authorisation Code Grant with confidential client.

Good example [here](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2013/10/25/securing-a-web-api-with-adfs-on-ws2012-r2-got-even-easier/).

Note that your ADFS provider is going to have to configure this. In particular, the fact that the RP configuration is done via PowerShell.

"Add-ADFSClient"